# How to persist a ForeignCollection with ormlite 4.42?

Tags: java, sqlite, ormlite, foreign-collection

I'm trying to persist a lazy [ForeignCollection](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#SEC30) with ormlite 4.42 and sqlite on a desktop application.

I have an `Event` class that holds a collection of `EventDate` :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "event")
public class Event extends BaseDaoEnabled<Event, Integer> implements Scrap {

     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
     private int id;

     @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
     private ForeignCollection<EventDate> dates;

}
```

The `EventDate` class is :

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "eventdate")
public class EventDate extends BaseDaoEnabled<EventDate, Integer> {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
    int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = true, foreign = true)
    Event event;

}
```

And here is the code I use to add the `EventDates` and persist them :

```
    Event e2 = eventDao.queryForId(id));

    e2.getDates().clear();
    for (final EventDate date : dates) {
        e2.getDates().add(date);
        e2.getDates().update(date);
    }
    e2.update();
```

The `EvenDates` are correctly added in the sqlite table, but the field `event_id` is null : the `EventDates` are not linked to the `Event`.

I have no error message. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Note : I tried with eager collection (adding `e2.getDates().updateAll()`) but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you set the Dao<T, ID> for the objects you want to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a missing feature here.  Right now you need to assign the event on the dates by hand before adding them to the dates collection:

```
e2.getDates().clear();
for (final EventDate date : dates) {
    // this is necessary unfortunately
    date.setEvent(e2);
    e2.getDates().add(date);
}
```

I've added the following ticket for review:

> https://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/feature-requests/31/

Comment: According to the request, the feature is now implemented in ormlite 4.43